# How to debug kernel mode driver in visual studio 2012 using virtual machine?

Tags: windows

I have Ubuntu 13.04 . I am running two windows x64 operating system in Oracle VM.
I have installed Visual studio 2012.
Can anybody please suggest how to debug two virtuals in visual studio.

Comment: Do you want to run debugger on one virtual Windows OS and debug driver on another virtual OS? In this case you need to connect serial ports of these two computers using host pipe. Maybe this link can help: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-serial-port-between-two-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox

Comment: Having this connection, you can configure one OS as debugee, and run kernel-mode debugger on another OS.

Comment: Hello in this configuration i get while deploying like "Kernel mode drivers cannot be deployed to the local machine"

Comment: So, you want to debug the driver which cannot be deployed? Looks like impossible task.. Is this hardware device driver or something else?

Comment: it is fake driver for practice.like hello world

Comment: From my experience, it is possible to install non-hardware drivers on a virtual computer. This is usually done on every driver development course. If you have some problem with this, ask separate question about this specific problem.